# Accessing private methods inside a singleton class methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If I have a ruby class similar to this:

```rb
class MyClass
  def self.singleton_method
    do_something_private
  end

  private

  def do_something_private
    puts "doing something private"
  end
end
```

And I call `MyClass.singleton_method`

Then I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `do_something_private' for MyClass:Class):
```

How can we resolve the error and what is the right way to define private methods which could be called from inside of class methods?

Comment: When `do_something_private` is invoked `self` is `MyClass`, but there is no (class) method `MyClass::do_something_private`, hence the error message.

Comment: Your `do_something_private` is an instance method.

Comment: _“what is the right way to define private methods which could be called from inside of class methods?”_ one cannot call instance methods from class methods for the obvious reason, despite whether they are private, public, or whatever.

Comment: This isn't really a "singleton method", it's a class method. Yes, instance methods on the class' singleton class are the same as class methods, but these are not usually referred to as "singleton methods"

Answer (score 3):

That's because `do_something_private` is defined as the instance method of `MyClass`. Change it to the class method:

```
def self.do_something_private
  # do something private
end
```

Worth reading the note from [@Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652654/accessing-private-methods-inside-a-singleton-class-methods-in-ruby/57652770?noredirect=1#comment101756086_57652770):

> Note that private doesn't do anything for class methods, it only makes instance methods private. You need private_class_method def self.do_something_private ... instead.

Comment: Note that `private` doesn't do anything for class methods, it only makes instance methods private. You need `private_class_method def self.do_something_private ...` instead.

Comment: Or you can define the class method as an instance method within `class << self` where `private` works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that you're calling an instance method from a class method. If you add `self` to your private method it will become a class method and can be called by the Class name.
Try 
`self.do_something_private`